# Is it possible to use an ArrayAdapter (no subclassing) with a custom View to display data?

Tags: android

Often, a simple of ArrayAdapter does what I want and during early development I will provide the android.R.simple_list_item_1 for the view id required by the ArrayAdapter constructor.  Is it possible to provide a customized view which is based on the android.R.simple_list_item_1 to the ArrayAdapter constructor?

I do not fully understand Android's 'include' functionality, but what I would like to do is something like:

- Define a new TextView based on customizing the android.R.simple_list_item_1.
  (I have no idea what the valid syntax would be)

e.g.

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MyTextView"
    android:textSize="20dip">
        <include android.R.simple_list_item_1/>
</TextView>
```

- Reference my customized TextView.  I assume that something like this would go into my layout directory.  Then in my code I would do something like:

  ```
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.id.MyTextView, null);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, view.getId(), myArrayOfData);
  ```

Is this possible and if it is, what is the appropriate syntax to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing just simple TextView (without include, or any reference to simple_list_item_1) and give it id: "@android:id/text1"

That's the id of TextView in simple_list_item_1.
Not really sure if this'll work (haven't tried such a thing), But my thinking is that it'll try to find TextView with such an ID and it will find it.

Here's source of simple_list_item_1 for reference:

> < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
>
> < TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@android:id/text1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:paddingLeft="6dip" android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" />

P.S. Here you can find source for android standart layouts here: http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/